# Temporal filtering on depth image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, shader, fragment-shader

I'm reading the following paper and I'm trying to implement it, but it seems I'm not understanding fully the paper.
[https://vcg.informatik.uni-rostock.de/~malub/publications/2016_depthenhance/16_ARLS_depthenhancement.pdf](https://vcg.informatik.uni-rostock.de/%7Emalub/publications/2016_depthenhance/16_ARLS_depthenhancement.pdf)

I have calculated optical flow and some history of the depth images, and took the a linear average over the history samples as shown in the shader code.

What I get is an image that has holes however the original one doesn't have any holes.

[image]

Current filtered image

[image]

Shader Implementation:

```
Shader "Unlit/DepthFilter"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _PrevTex("_PrevTex", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CurrentDepth("Current Depth", 2D) = "white" {}
        _HistoryA("History A", 2D) = "white" {}
        _HistoryB("History B", 2D) = "white" {}
        _HistoryC("History C", 2D) = "white" {}

        _dataDelta("Data Delta", range(0, 256)) = 256
        _Lambda("Lambda", Range(0.0, 0.1)) = 0.015
        _Threshold("Threshold", Range(0.0, 10)) = 0.046
        _Scale("_Scale", Range(0.0, 10)) = 1.33

    }
        SubShader
        {
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
            LOD 100

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                sampler2D _PrevTex;
                float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
                sampler2D _CurrentDepth;
                sampler2D _HistoryA;
                sampler2D _HistoryB;
                sampler2D _HistoryC;
                float     _dataDelta;
                float _Scale, _Lambda, _Threshold;
                float4 gradient(sampler2D tex, float2 uv, float2 offset)
                {
                    return (tex2D(tex, uv + offset)) - (tex2D(tex, uv - offset));
                }

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {


                    float2 uv = i.uv;
                    float4 current = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                    float4 prev = tex2D(_PrevTex, uv);
                     
                    float2 dx = float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, 0);
                    float2 dy = float2(0, _MainTex_TexelSize.y);

                    float4 diff = current - prev;

                    float4 gx = gradient(_PrevTex, uv, dx) + gradient(_MainTex, uv, dx);
                    float4 gy = gradient(_PrevTex, uv, dy) + gradient(_MainTex, uv, dy);

                    float4 gmag = sqrt(gx * gx + gy * gy + float4(_Lambda, _Lambda, _Lambda, _Lambda));
                    float4 invGmag = 1.0 / gmag;
                    float4 vx = diff * (gx * invGmag);
                    float4 vy = diff * (gy * invGmag);

                    float2 flow = float2(0, 0);
                    const float inv3 = 0.33333;
                    flow.x = -(vx.x + vx.y + vx.z) * inv3;
                    flow.y = -(vy.x + vy.y + vy.z) * inv3;

                    float w = length(flow);
                    float nw = (w - _Threshold) / (1.0 - _Threshold);
                    flow = lerp(float2(0, 0), normalize(flow) * nw * _Scale, step(_Threshold, w));
                    
                    float2 curr = tex2D(_CurrentDepth, i.uv).xy;

                    float2 last_depth_frame_1 = tex2D(_HistoryA, i.uv).xy;
                    float2 last_depth_frame_2 = tex2D(_HistoryB, i.uv).xy;
                    float2 last_depth_frame_3 = tex2D(_HistoryC, i.uv).xy;

                    float2 last_depth_avg = (last_depth_frame_1 + last_depth_frame_2 + last_depth_frame_3) / 3.0;

                    float2 average_at_pixel;
                    average_at_pixel.x = curr.x + last_depth_avg.x - flow.x;
                    average_at_pixel.y = curr.y + last_depth_avg.y - flow.y;
                    fixed c = average_at_pixel;
                    //float4 velocity = float4(flow, 0,1);
                    //return float4(abs(velocity.xy), 0, 1);
                    return c;


                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your interpolation mode?

Comment: @Immersive             _historyPages.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;

Comment: Please show the list of original depth image.  My theory is the original depth image reconstriction is bad for lacking robust features at center of the paper. that why you have this result. No matter how many depth you are fusing, it wont help much

Comment: If i understand this issue corrrectly, the optical flow based depth averaging wont help. You need techniques such as depth completion. Depth completion aims to recover dense depth maps from sparse depth measurements

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai The original problem is flickering that is shown in my experiement here https://youtu.be/qUcimP-DIZk if you notice there are a LOT of flickering

Comment: the flickering may be caused by wrong depth prediction or wrong parameter in the segmentation code. can you try to show the depth predicted with the RGB image side by side?

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I'm getting the original depth from Zed camera, that's all, not doing anything more just distanced based cut out

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I will do it for you, can you please look at my other comment on the other post

Comment: i mean the orignial depth image from ZED may not be perfect and need post processing. ZED used a very high smoothing parameter which may cause many type of error

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai that's why I used optical flow based temporal filter

Comment: for systematic error which appear in every frame, the optical flow based temporal filter may not help

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai it actually didn't help don't know what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224979/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-dr-yuan-shenghai).